# in C++, How can I overload an operator without passing an object through the parameters?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

For example, I'd like the following to output the number 6, but every example I've ever seen of operator overloading contains a "const" object in the parameters.

```
Class MyClass
{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        //Setter
        void setNum(int x)            {num = x;}

        //Getter
        int getNum()                  {return x;}

        //Overloading + Operator
        MyClass operator + (int add)
        {
        }
};

int Main()
{
    MyClass test;
    test.setNum(2);
    test = test + 4;
    cout << test.getNum();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An operator without an object in the parameters would be a negative operator or function operator, I don't think your question is worded correctly.

Comment: Your code is fine but you actually have to put some code inside the `operator+` function. And you do pass `add` through the parameters. The binary `+` operator has to have two arguments, there's no getting around that.

Comment: The question is very confusing. There's no contradiction in having your code output `6` and a `const` operator: `MyClass operator+(int add) const { MyClass x = *this; x.num += add; return x; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that does what you want:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        int num;
    public:
        //Setter
        void setNum(int x)            {num = x;}

        //Getter
        int getNum()                  {return num;}

        //Overloading + Operator
        MyClass operator + (int add)
        {
            MyClass copy;
            copy.num = num + add;
            return copy;
        }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass test;
    test.setNum(2);
    test = test + 4;
    std::cout << test.getNum();
    return 0;
}
```

Your code had a number of compiler errors that have also been fixed. For instance, Class should be class and Main should be main.

Comment: `operator+` should not modify the class, it should return a new value independent of the class. `operator+=` would modify the class.